# How to load Multidimensional array values into vector?

Tags: c++, vector

This is part of the code (header and the main part):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <RassHost.h>
#include <api\iomap.h>
#include <api\iotrans.h>
#include <api\cgeometry.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter IP: " << endl;
    getline(cin, server_ip);

    enum(KEY_L = 'A', KEY_R = 'D', KEY_RUN = 'WW', KEY_JUMP='SPACE');

    typedef OBJECT_3D_SYS_TYPES_NUM OBJECT3D_RCN_TYPE;

    OBJECT3D_RCN_TYPE _psyObjects[][] = getPsyhicsPartObjects();

    vector<OBJECT3D_RCN_TYPE> _objects;

    //I would like to load _psyObjects[][] into vector<OBJECT3D_RCN_TYPE> _objects;

    Server::StartGame(Server::getIP(), 8888, "-r run", false);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to copy `_psyObjects` values into `vector<OBJECT3D_RCN_TYPE>`?

I want to control the multidimensional array with vector api, if it is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: A vector is one dimensional but there is nothing stopping you from having a vector of vectors if you really need a two-dimensional array ... sorry can't provide a decent code snippet without knowing more about the types you're using here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a vector of vectors:

```
vector< vector<OBJECT3D_RCN_TYPE> > _objects;
```

Then just fill it like a normal vector.

I'd post more code, but you need to know the dimensions of the array, and I can't see those from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [`Boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html). It's api is like `std::vector`'s, but possibly similar enough to meet your needs.